# descr : Residuals not displaying in CrossTable command in R

Tags: r

Aloha!

I am trying to duplicate the analysis here: http://www.daleidoscope.com/chispssr/

but also want to see the residuals produced.

Using the commands:

```
library("descr")
chidata <- matrix(c(23,45,21,52),nrow=2,ncol=2)
chidata
CrossTable(chidata)
```

I can produce the correct table

and

```
CrossTable(chidata, chisq = T)
```

produces the correct chi-square

but when I use any of the residual commands such as:

```
CrossTable(chidata, chisq = T, resid=T, sresid=T, asresid=T)
```

only the table and the chi-square are produced and the residuals are not displayed.

I found this error when I ran the example from the Crosstable ?help also:

```
# Simple cross tabulation of education versus prior induced abortions
# using infertility data
data(infert, package = "datasets")
CrossTable(infert$education, infert$induced, expected = TRUE, asresid= TRUE)
```

which also left out the residual results.

Is there a way to make them display?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post outputs of all three `CrossTable()`? Does first two chi-squared output exactly the same? Otherwise we have to take your word for it. Even run `str(chidata)` for underlying structure of object.

Comment: I can only guess that you have unwittingly created an object named `T` and should instead use TRUE (as is always the case). The 'T' for `TRUE` sort of laziness is not the kind that Larry Wall was encouraging: http://threevirtues.com/

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I tried to include the output but it was over the character limit (too long by 591 characters), but yes, the output is exactly the same for `CrossTable(chidata, chisq = TRUE)` and for  `CrossTable(chidata, chisq = TRUE, resid=TRUE, sresid=TRUE, asresid=TRUE)` .  I also changed all the code from T to TRUE but the output did not change, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I get:

```
> CrossTable(chidata, chisq = T, resid=T, sresid=T, asresid=T) 
   Cell Contents 
|-------------------------|
|                       N | 
| Chi-square contribution | 
|           N / Row Total | 
|           N / Col Total | 
|         N / Table Total | 
|                Residual | 
|            Std Residual | 
|           Adj Std Resid | 
|-------------------------|

================================
           [,1]     [,2]   Total
--------------------------------
[1,]         23       21      44
          0.149    0.139        
          0.523    0.477   0.312
          0.338    0.288        
          0.163    0.149        
          0.648   -0.648        
--------------------------------
[2,]         45       52      97
          0.068    0.063        
          0.464    0.536   0.688
          0.662    0.712        
          0.319    0.369        
         -0.648    0.648        
--------------------------------
Total        68       73     141
          0.482    0.518        
================================

Statistics for All Table Factors

Pearson's Chi-squared test 
------------------------------------------------------------
Chi^2 = 0.419286      d.f. = 1      p = 0.517 

Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction 
------------------------------------------------------------
Chi^2 = 0.216829      d.f. = 1      p = 0.641
```

So if this isn't what you expected (or are seeing) then perhaps you need to post version numbers for "everything".

Comment: That is also what I get, and, like yours, the residuals, the standard residuals, and the adjusted standard residuals are not displayed. Only the table and the overall Chi-squares are shown. I am using R 3.3.0 and descr 1.1.2

Comment: Wade-a-minute: that has all the residuals displayed. (Albeit as per N, but that is what is "advertised".)

Comment: yes--you are right -- I have both code that produces it and some that does not--I am going back to check--thanks so much!

Comment: Residuals were not shown for me too. I tried to add `format = "SPSS"` to the CrossTable function call and residuals appeared

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of clarity, I had the same problem and the solution posted in the comments by @lucazav resolved the issue for me.

Needed to add `format = "SPSS"` to the CrossTable function call:

```
chidata <- matrix(c(23,45,21,52),nrow=2,ncol=2)
chidata
CrossTable(chidata, chisq = T, resid=T, sresid=T, asresid=T, format = "SPSS")
```

Output:

```
   Cell Contents
|-------------------------|
|                   Count |
| Chi-square contribution |
|             Row Percent |
|          Column Percent |
|           Total Percent |
|                Residual |
|            Std Residual |
|           Adj Std Resid |
|-------------------------|

Total Observations in Table:  141 

             |  
             |     [,1]  |     [,2]  | Row Total | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
        [1,] |       23  |       21  |       44  | 
             |    0.149  |    0.139  |           | 
             |   52.273% |   47.727% |   31.206% | 
             |   33.824% |   28.767% |           | 
             |   16.312% |   14.894% |           | 
             |    1.780  |   -1.780  |           | 
             |    0.386  |   -0.373  |           | 
             |    0.648  |   -0.648  |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
        [2,] |       45  |       52  |       97  | 
             |    0.068  |    0.063  |           | 
             |   46.392% |   53.608% |   68.794% | 
             |   66.176% |   71.233% |           | 
             |   31.915% |   36.879% |           | 
             |   -1.780  |    1.780  |           | 
             |   -0.260  |    0.251  |           | 
             |   -0.648  |    0.648  |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
Column Total |       68  |       73  |      141  | 
             |   48.227% |   51.773% |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|


Statistics for All Table Factors


Pearson's Chi-squared test 
------------------------------------------------------------
Chi^2 =  0.419286     d.f. =  1     p =  0.5172935 

Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction 
------------------------------------------------------------
Chi^2 =  0.216829     d.f. =  1     p =  0.6414668 


       Minimum expected frequency: 21.21986
```